# array[i].(split) is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

Trying to sort through an array for artists that lived through the twentieth century. The numbers in the year property of the array are strings rather than numbers:
`"years" : "1471 - 1528"`
So I'm trying to split all the years, convert them to numbers, then compare the numbers that way. But when I log to console, I get an error that says "array[i].split is not a function". I've tried `array.years.split(" ")` and gotten an error as well. I'm just learning JS so bear with me if it's an obvious mistake, but can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Here's a part of the array:

```
const artists = [
  { "name": "artist name", "years": "1884 - 1920"} ,
...
]

function getYears (array) {
 const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   const splitYears = array[i].split(" ");
   splitYears.splice("-")
   Math.floor(splitYears);
    if (splitYears[0] > 1900 && splitYears[1] < 2000) {
      return newArray.push(array[i].name);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
console.log(getYears(artists));
```

Comment: Can u show what argument have you passes in `get20s` function

Comment: can you provide the input array? is it in an object like this `[{years:"1471 - 1528"}]`, or just an element like this `["1471 - 1528"]`

Answer (score 3):

I'm only guessing because you aren't showing the full content of the array, but I suspect you want something closer to:

`array[i].year.split(" ")`

Further, rather that split on the spaces, it would make more sense to split on the spaces and the dash together, using a regex that doesn't care about how many spaces (if any) are present:

`array[i].year.split(/\s*-\s*/)`

The above will return a single-element array when there is one year, a two-element array when a range of years is given.

One further step would be to convert the array to numbers instead of strings:

`array[i].year.split(/\s*-\s*/).map(n => parseInt(n, 10))`

Comment: I'd go with `parseFloat(n)` or `parseInt(n, 10)`

Comment: I took your suggestion, @Phil, and added the radix. I'm used to using a utility function `toNumber()` that's not built-in, so I don't think about `parseInt` very often anymore.

Comment: @kshetline I was told `Math.floor` could function like `toNumber()` but I think `parseInt` is doing the trick for this now! I'm not getting the split error anymore! However I still have some more debugging to do lol Thanks!

Comment: @beepbopdev, `Math.floor` converts any *number* into an integer value (by always rounding down), but it doesn't convert strings.